# group_by tidyverse in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create some baseball statistics and I'm looking to group some data by league. So I'm looking for runs/inning surrendered by relief pitchers, by league.

```
relief_pitching_stats %>%
  group_by(League) %>%
  summarise(
    total_inn = sum(IP),
    runs_per_inn = sum(total_ER) / sum(total_inn)
  )
```

I would expect the output to look something like

```
League  total_inn   runs_per_inn
AL      500         .5
NL      700         .4
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
 total_inn runs_per_inn
1   18205.2    0.4630835
```

Can you tell me what I've done wrong here to not get the grouping correct. I expect given the differences in rules between the two leagues for the run/inning to be different, so I do want to group the stat by league.

thanks.

Here's what the df looks like when I load it into R.

[image: relief_pitching_stats]

```
> dput(head(relief_pitching_stats))
structure(list(Team = c("TBR", "CHW", "NYY", "SEA", "LAD", "SFG"
), League = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "NL", "NL"), W = c(58L, 
32L, 48L, 45L, 41L, 49L), L = c(32L, 29L, 30L, 27L, 28L, 22L), 
    SV = c(42L, 43L, 47L, 51L, 56L, 56L), G = c(531L, 512L, 512L, 
    584L, 600L, 599L), GS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), IP = c(703, 
    548, 606, 618.2, 608.2, 623.2), K.9 = c(9.46, 10.58, 10.02, 
    9.06, 9.64, 8.37), BB.9 = c(2.82, 3.45, 3.36, 3.13, 3.98, 
    2.73), HR.9 = c(1, 1.15, 1.08, 0.93, 0.89, 0.95), BABIP = c(0.278, 
    0.298, 0.282, 0.286, 0.257, 0.262), LOB. = c("74.60%", "72.70%", 
    "72.70%", "69.40%", "73.60%", "74.30%"), GB. = c("41.50%", 
    "42.40%", "46.50%", "42.40%", "47.30%", "43.40%"), HR.FB = c("10.70%", 
    "12.90%", "13.40%", "10.10%", "11.40%", "10.00%"), vFA..pi. = c(93.7, 
    96, 95.5, 93.7, 94.2, 93.6), ERA = c(3.24, 3.97, 3.56, 3.88, 
    3.16, 2.99), xERA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FIP = c(3.59, 
    3.75, 3.76, 3.72, 3.83, 3.71), xFIP = c(3.98, 3.83, 3.78, 
    4.18, 4.07, 4.2), WAR = c(7.9, 7.8, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 5.4), games_pitched = c(78.1111111111111, 
    60.8888888888889, 67.3333333333333, 68.6888888888889, 67.5777777777778, 
    69.2444444444445), total_ER = c(253.08, 241.728888888889, 
    239.706666666667, 266.512888888889, 213.545777777778, 207.040888888889
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the ``relief_pitching_stats`` please.

Comment: ... by posting the output from `dput(head(relief_pitching_stats))` into a code block, thank you!

Comment: Two guesses: (1) are `IP`, `total_ER`, and `total_inn` vectors in your environment? (2) If you just type in `summarise`, does the last line on the console say `<environment: namespace:dplyr>` or `<environment: namespace:plyr>`? (If the latter, change to using `dplyr::summarise` for now, and change the order that you load libraries, loading `dplyr` after `plyr`.)

Comment: thanks. adding dplyr::summarise has solved the problem. thank you.